# Linq to Excel Not Retrieving First Populated Row

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

I'm just starting out in Linq to Excel today, so I assume I've missed something rather simple.

I want to print the entire contents of an Excel Worksheet, But the ExcelQueryable object is not returning the first populated row.

The syntax I've used is as follows:

```
var excel_query_factory = new ExcelQueryFactory(directory);
var worksheet = excel_query_factory.Worksheet(worksheet_name);
```

The test spreadsheet is just a 5x5 table of the range B2:F6.

The query results are of the range C2:F6.

How should I specify that I do not wish the first populated row skipped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're skipping the first row, it may be because it's thinking the first row is a header. Try the following:

```
var excel_query_factory = new ExcelQueryFactory(directory);
var worksheet = excel_query_factory.WorksheetNoHeader(worksheet_name);
```

See the documentation [here](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel). Query a worksheet without a header row. See also the Query a specific range within a worksheet to use No Header as well.

```
var yourRange = from c in excel_query_factory.WorksheetRangeNoHeader("B2", "F6")
```